# How to fix error with python spark UDF that runs ok on Databricks but not locally on DBX

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks-dbx

I am getting an error when trying to use a python spark UDF. It works on databricks, but not in my local DBX environment. It seems to occur when I use an external library. Other UDFs work fine. Is there something I perhaps need to do to make the function from an external library work inside of my local spark environment?

Example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from lib import func

func(1) # works

test_udf = F.udf(func, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("udf_output", test_udf(F.lit(1))) # doesn't work
```

I've tried increasing the memory in the spark config, but this didn't help

```
_builder = (
        SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]")
        .config("spark.hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", Path(warehouse_dir).as_uri())
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "12g")
        .config(
            "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
            "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
        )
    )
```

Error message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:577)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
```

Answer (score 0):

The library needs to be availble to the python interpreter.  This is pretty well covered on how to do this [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html).

Use a environment tool(see link) or pass the library via commandline.

> Setting the configuration setting spark.submit.pyFiles
>
> Setting --py-files option in Spark scripts
>
> Directly calling pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile() in applications